# Operador de comparacion

Tags: javascript

¿Por qué si intento comparar `new String("0") === "0"` me da false?
¿Será que al usar el operador `new` el tipo cambia?

Comment: Por que el primero es las instancia de un objeto y el segundo es una cadena. Y si... Javascript tiene estas cosas raras. [Más info](https://javascriptwtf.com/) y ["MDN > Comparadores de igualdad e identidad"](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)

Comment: Voto por reabrir esta pregunta , porque esta pregunta es de `primitivos vs objeto` mas que de `== vs ===`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Como explica la doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/String#string_constructor_and_string_function), Javascript tiene lo que se llama **Constructor de cadenas** y **función de cadena**.

La función de cadena produce un resultado del tipo `String`, mientras que el constructor de cadena, que es lo que estás usando, produce un resultado del tipo `object`. Al hacer una comparación estricta con `===`, te da false, porque `new String("0")` no es del mismo tipo que `"0"`.

Vamos a verlo en un ejemplo:

```js
let a=new String("0");
let b="0";

//Comparación estricta
console.log(a === b);
//Comparación no estricta
console.log(a == b);
//Verificando tipos
console.log(`tipo de a: ${typeof a}`);
console.log(`tipo de b: ${typeof b}`);
```

Convendría leer el apartado [Comparadores de igualdad e identidad](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness). Si analizas la tabla mostrada allí, verás que dos objectos `new String("0")` no cumplen ningún criterio de igualdad basado en operadores. Ocurre algo similar a lenguajes como Java o C, en los cuales debes usar `equals()` para saber si dos instancias de un objeto son iguales. En Javascript puedes usar otras técnicas, por ejemplo, comparar por valor, usando `valueOf()`.

```js
let c=new String("0");
let d=new String("0");
console.log(c===d);
console.log(c==d);
console.log(Object.is(c,d));
//Comparando los valores
console.log(c.valueOf()===d.valueOf());
```